# Spring No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and no explicit mapping for /error for login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring

I've been trying to create a login page in react in order to login on the spring backend I've created. However when I send the request to login I get the following error:

`POST http://localhost:8080/login 403 ()`

`login:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I looked at the response headers and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is indeed not present.

This is the request I'm doing:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      Accept: 'application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password}
  })
```

My filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Here's my security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

I also get the following error when visiting localhost:8080/login directly:

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Aug 16 10:42:17 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 403* indicates it’s not the browser that’s blocking you in this case but instead the server isn’t allowing POST requests to `http://localhost:8080/login`. That is, it’s not a CORS problem, and it seems like you’ll run into the same 403 if you try that POST request from postman or curl or whatever other non-browser client/tool. So I guess you need to figure out why your server’s responding with a 403 and how to configure it to respond with 200 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the webpack server for the client, and a different server for your backend. For security purposes, the current web browsers don't allow cross domain request (your `localhost:3000` is calling `localhost:8080`, two different domains).

There is two way to fix this:

- Make a proxy from your webpack server to your backend server
- Serve your client from your backend server

For the second option, I'll let you see how you could do it regarding the libraries you're using. Generally you need to define your backend routes match first, and then serve your client for all the default route (if you have a Single Page Application), or just serve your client for the "/" route.

For the proxy, you can see a detailed explanation on [this blog post](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/#the-rub-). Basically, since it seems you already have both of your servers running, it just a matter of adding this to your wepback config:

```
{
   ...
   "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
}
```

Comment: I tried the proxy approach which results in me getting 404:
`POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)`
this seems consistent with me getting 404 when visiting localhost:8080/login directly so I guess the problem lies there now.

Comment: I can't help with Spring, sorry. Never used it, and I left the Java world a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch api will not work directly when you use react and spring together as there is no mode of connection between both back end and front end.

Like in jsp on form submission action  binds to spring controller automatically.

In this case you made need something like:

- Isomorphic web applications which uses nashorn(java8) engine to call
  your client side js files

[isomorphic apps](https://blog.pusher.com/realtime-shopping-cart-with-java-and-react/)

- Using pusher api which dispatches your action and client side listen to that and hence they communicate[using pusher api](https://blog.pusher.com/realtime-shopping-cart-with-java-and-react/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your backend to accept requests from other origins, this is happening because your front end is totally isolated from your backend. You could solve this by configuring your nginx to serve as a reverse proxy.

I assume you're using RESTful APIs to communicate with your backend. Browsers inherently don't send CORS requests. You need to send a [CORS request](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Try whitelisting your IP address of your front end server on your backend so it can accept requests from the front-end server.